# Hyperlink in ArcGIS JavaScript API map identify dialog?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, hyperlink, url

IBM's [Maximo Spatial 7.6.1](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSG2D3_7.6.0/com.ibm.spl.doc/welcome.html) uses the ArcGIS JavaScript API/map service to serve up a web map to Maximo:

[image]

In the Maximo map, I've included URLs as values in the GIS layer.

I want to be able to use the URLs as hyperlinks in Maximo that would open in a new tab/window in the browser.

Is there something I can do on the GIS side so that the URLs are treated as hyperlinks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using only the ESRI Javascript API and pure javascript to construct your infobox, you'll need to code some html for that field in the content of the infobox's template.
for instance: "DESCRIPTION: http://mylink> Link "

If you're using an ArcGISONline or Portal webmap to configure your popup, then it should detect the http and make a link automatically, but it doesnt look like you are using that here...

Answer (score 0):

As @ericoneal mentioned, the solution was to use HTML in the URL.

- The webpage opens in a new tab in Google Chrome (which is good). 
  `Chrome Version 79.0.3945.130 (Official Build) (64-bit)`

`<a href='http://maps.google.com/maps?q=&layer=c&cbll=43.000000,-78.000000'> Link </a>`

[image]

---

The SQL behind this is:

```
'<a href=''http://maps.google.com/maps?q=' ||chr(38)|| 'layer=c' ||chr(38)|| 
    'cbll=43.000000,-78.000000''> Link </a>' as description,
```

> Hint:
>
> In Toad, the ampersand was being interpreted as a variable.  I had to escape/replace the ampersand with `||chr(38)||`. [Escaping
>   ampersand character in SQL string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12961550/10936066)